# Magento doesn't support camelCase in URL/route?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, xml, routing

If you are declaring your router in `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml` with similar way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="myModule" frontName="myModule">
            <module name="My_Module" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

it doesn't work. In my case my base url will be `/admin/myModule/index/index`.

I was pushed to replace `myModule` with `my_module` (in URL in XML, at least in `frontName` attribute, and rename layout/handle filename).

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to keep layout/handle file in lower case.

E.g. we have request:

```
myModule/someController/massUpdate
```

Handle filename should be in lower case:

```
mymodule_somecontroller_massupdate.xml
```

So, there is some debug experience:

Method `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout::getDefaultLayoutHandle()` has converting to lowercase:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the default layout handle name for the current action
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDefaultLayoutHandle()
{
    return strtolower($this->request->getFullActionName());
}
```

and there xpath request for the handle node:

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge::_fetchPackageLayoutUpdates

foreach ($layout->xpath("*[self::handle or self::layout][@id='{$handle}']") as $updateXml) {
        //...
    }
```

and it looks like it's case-sensitive.